# how to get click event from a button in gridview in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult MyGrid()
    {
        List<User> li = new List<User>();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Connection.Connection con = new Connection.Connection();
        ds = con.mydata();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            li.Add(new User 
            {
                Name=dr["Name"].ToString(),
                Email= dr["Email"].ToString(),
                MobileNo= dr["MobileNo"].ToString()
            });
        }
        return View(li);
    }
```

This is my View (.cshtml file). I have created a Grid and added a button in it using code below.

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 5);
@grid.GetHtml(

tableStyle: "table", // applying style on grid

fillEmptyRows: true,
    //show empty row when there is only one record on page to it will display all empty rows there.
headerStyle: "header", //applying style.

footerStyle: "grid-footer", //applying style.

mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, //paging to grid
firstText: "<< First",
previousText: "< Prev",
nextText: "Next >",
lastText: "Last >>",

columns: new[]  // colums in grid
{
    grid.Column("Name"), //the model fields to display
    grid.Column("Email"  ),
    grid.Column("MobileNo"),
    grid.Column("Action", format: @<text>
        <button >Edit</button>
        </text>,  style: "col3Width" , canSort: false), })
```

I want to perform an action when I click on Edit Button in Grid. How can I do that?

Comment: There should be some unique `Id` for each record which you have to send through your controller while filling the `li` and it is just to attach with each element and not to display. Now if you say `email` can be considered as unique `Id` then attach that email as `data-*` attribute to your each Edit button and write a common javascript function for each button and call it on click and extract this `data-*` attribute to manipulate it again in the controller.

Comment: Yes you can!! Jus replace your button with actionLink and attach extra url attribute say `id` to it.. :)

Comment: I tried that but its not getting done. I explained the issue that im getting please provide the necesary changes that is to be done. Thanxx